# Column formatting unix

Tags: unix, awk, formatting

So the issue I am having is to format the column to give it more space so i am unsure how to give column mode more spaces so everything lines up. now my awk statement just formats it so that each field is separated so that people without middle names does not screw it up lol.

```
 $ cat file

1 Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as 
2 Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab 
3 Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

That's the original file so I used the awk statement below to field separate each column so that the middle name wouldn't try to group another column into it

```
$ echo "#  ""Name             ""LS     ""mode       ""food   ""item   ""num   ""list   "
$ echo "-  ""---------------  ""-----  ""---------  ""-------""-----  ""----  ""-----  "
$ awk -v OFS='~' '{$2=$2" "$3;$3=""} 
        NF==10{$2=$2" "$4;$4=""} 
         NF==9{$3=$3 OFS ""}1' file | column -ts~
#  Name             LS     mode       food   item   num   list   
-  ---------------  -----  ---------  -----  -----  ----  -----  
1  Jackson, Bob D.  C0001  book    pizza  apple  4.00  123as
2  Filer, Jack      C0002  happy   apple  hat    4.00  124ab
3  Metro, Jim K.    C0003  kindle  pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

So what i want this to come out as is.  If you have a better way then just echo those items in feel free to edit but if its fine that why it does not really matter i just need the final output to look like this thanks!

```
#  Name             LS     mode       food   item   num   list   
-  ---------------  -----  ---------  -----  -----  ----  -----  
1  Jackson, Bob D.  C0001  book       pizza  apple  4.00  123as
2  Filer, Jack      C0002  happy      apple  hat    4.00  124ab
3  Metro, Jim K.    C0003  kindle     pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

Comment: you should post your input file data rather than the outcome of `awk` statement.

Comment: OK added the original file sorry didn't even think about that when I posted it

Comment: Now, the question is clear & shows enough research. As for the solution, You can use `printf` as mentioned in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36256406/5832518)

Comment: Now will I not have to use field separates like I did in my previous code? Because like I kept having issues where for Filer, Jack C0002 would try to become it's middle name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

I'll solve the name problem for you in a different way and show how to use printf for formatting, you can add the headers and rest of fields looking up the answer above.

```
    $ awk 'NF==9{for(i=NF;i>=4;i--) $(i+1)=$i; $4=""}
                {printf "%d %-15s %5s\n", $1,$2" "$3" "$4, $5}' file

1 Jackson, Bob D. C0001
2 Filer, Jack     C0002
3 Metro, Jim K.   C0003
```

Comment: Perfect dude thanks for coming to save me again lol this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Now is there any way to calculate what we should NF equal to? Like if we didn't know how long the person's name is that doesn't have a middle initial?

Comment: Here it assumes it's one less than the full 10 fields.  If there is another missing field there is no other way.  The field delimiter should be set correctly in the original file (not white space) so the fields and field count can be correctly identified.  Lacking that this is the heuristics you can use.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is your friend.

#### example

```
awk '{ printf "%-30s %s \n", $1, $2 }' inputfile.txt
```

In the above example, first column will be 30 characters left justified.

#### `awk printf` supported datatypes

```
%i or d --Decimal
%o --Octal
%x --hex
%c --ASCII number character
%s --String
%f --floating number
```

#### Padding options

```
-n --Pad n spaces on right hand side of a column.
n --Pad n spaces on left hand side of a column.
.m --Add zeros on left side.
-n.m --Pad n spaces right hand side and add m zeros before that number.
n.m --Pad n spaces left hand side and add m zeros before that.
```

Using above details, we can rewrite `awk` statement like this

```
awk 'BEGIN { format = "%d %-15s %5s %-9s %-5s %-5s %1.2d %5s \n"
             printf format, "#", "Name", "LS", "mode","food","item","num   ","list"
             printf format, "-","---------------","-----","---------","-----","-----","----","-----" }
           { printf format, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7,$8 }' inputfile.txt
```

#### perl solution

```
$ perl -lane 'printf "%d%-15s%5s%-9s%-5s%-5s%-5s%1.2d%5s\n",@F' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother figuring out how many names the person has. You know the last 6 fields are the "values", and the first field is the number, and whatever's left are the names. The index arithmetic is a bit tricky but not too bad:

```
awk '
    # too bad awk doesn't have a built-in join function
    function join(sepstr, array, len,       sep, i, result) {
        sep = ""
        result = ""
        for (i=1; i <= len; i++) {
            result = result sep array[i]
            sep = sepstr
        }
        return result
    }
    BEGIN {print "#:Name:LS:mode:food:item:num:list"}
    {
        delete result
        result[1] = $1
        for (i=1; i <= 6; i++) result[i+2] = $(NF-6+i)
        delete names
        len=0
        for (i=2; i <= NF-6; i++) {names[i-1] = $i; len++}
        result[2] = join(" ", names, len)
        print join(":", result, 8)
    }
' file | column -t -s:
```

```
#  Name             LS     mode    food   item   num   list
1  Jackson, Bob D.  C0001  book    pizza  apple  4.00  123as
2  Filer, Jack      C0002  happy   apple  hat    4.00  124ab
3  Metro, Jim K.    C0003  kindle  pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

If you really need the separator, pipe the `column` output into

```
perl -lpe 'if ($. == 2) {($line=$_) =~ s/(\S+.*?)($|  (?=\S))/ "-" x length($1) . $2 /ge; print $line}'
```

to get

```
#  Name             LS     mode    food   item   num   list
-  ---------------  -----  ------  -----  -----  ----  -----
1  Jackson, Bob D.  C0001  book    pizza  apple  4.00  123as
2  Filer, Jack      C0002  happy   apple  hat    4.00  124ab
3  Metro, Jim K.    C0003  kindle  pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

---

Note, if you're not tied to awk, perl is much more concise. Perl's array manipulation functions far out-strip awk. As shown below we have `shift`/`unshift` which remove/add elements from the front of a list, and `pop`/`push` which remove/add elements from the end of a list:

```
perl -lane '
    BEGIN {print "#:Name:LS:mode:food:item:num:list"}
    undef @res;
    unshift @res, pop @F for 1..6;
    $n = shift @F;
    unshift @res, $n, join(" ", @F);
    print join(":", @res)
' file | column -t -s:
```